# pandas ffill and bfill based on condition in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like

```
data = {
    "ReportName": ["Sample cycle", 'Message',  "ID", "m1", "Uncertainty m1", "Message", "Sample cycle", 'Message', "ID", "m0", "Uncertainty m0", "Message", "ID", "m1", "Uncertainty m1", "Message"],
    "Values": [ "1","NO", "II", None, None, "NO", "1", "NO", "ID1", "1.8", "0.43", "NO", "ID2", "1.5", "0.41", "NO"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I I created a new "ID" column with this function

```
def extract_id(row):
    if row['ReportName'] == 'ID':
        return row['Values']
    return None
```

Now I want fill Na with ID from ReportName == 'Sample cycle' to next 'Sample cycle'.

Desired output

```
        ReportName Values    ID
0     Sample cycle      1  None
1          Message     NO    II
2               ID     II    II
3               m1   None    II
4   Uncertainty m1   None    II
5          Message     NO    II
6     Sample cycle      1  None
7          Message     NO   ID1
8               ID    ID1   ID1
9               m0    1.8   ID1
10  Uncertainty m0   0.43   ID1
11         Message     NO   ID1
12              ID    ID2   ID2
13              m1    1.5   ID2
14  Uncertainty m1   0.41   ID2
15         Message     NO   ID2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform) with masks:

```
# identify rows with ID
m1 = df['ReportName'].eq('ID')
# identify rows with "Sample cycle"
# this is used both to form groups
# and to mask the output
m2 = df['ReportName'].eq('Sample cycle')

df.loc[~m2, 'ID'] = (df['Values'].where(m1).groupby(m2.cumsum())
                     .transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
                    )
```

Output:

```
        ReportName Values   ID
0     Sample cycle      1  NaN
1          Message     NO   II
2               ID     II   II
3               m1   None   II
4   Uncertainty m1   None   II
5          Message     NO   II
6     Sample cycle      1  NaN
7          Message     NO  ID1
8               ID    ID1  ID1
9               m0    1.8  ID1
10  Uncertainty m0   0.43  ID1
11         Message     NO  ID1
12              ID    ID2  ID2
13              m1    1.5  ID2
14  Uncertainty m1   0.41  ID2
15         Message     NO  ID2
```